# Ubuntu 18.04-Vmware Worksation 15.5.2 networking issues

Tags: openstack, vmware-workstation, esx

I have networking issues with vmware workstation v15.5.2 on Ubuntu 18.04.
I installed ESXi and Openstack on vmware worksation with NAT, Host-only and Bridged adapters each time, then I set up a vm inside the ESXi/Openstack VM, I could ping the Vm inside openstack/esxi to the Workstation vm where was installed ESXi and Openstack, the ping is also successful from host machine to the workstation VM, but impossible to ping either way between Host machine and VMs created inside Openstack/ESxi.

-Here's the strange part:

I did the exact same labs with the exact same config (mainly out-the-box installations) on WINDOWS 10 Vmware workstation v15.5.2, and the ping worked just fine for the 3 scenarios mentioned above.

So to summarize, the VMs created within an openstack/esxi VM can't reach outside of their parent VM, not even the different gateways of vmware workstation different network/adapter types

I tried to uninstall VMware workstation and install again but the problem remains.
has anyone ever noticed this or is there an extra configuration to do on Ubuntu Vmware that is not needed on Windows?
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

someone found the answer thanks to him.
https://gist.github.com/mhtsai1010/e6f3442cefc34ae7069dc2b5e690577c?fbclid=IwAR1thxO__0PCms_jTB7nDdVrXTC2FupCdrzoE9E59TWxQHMbIXCuGMbyRWk

https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Pro/15.0/com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-089D2595-26C5-433B-9DA4-D2A94C63B7B5.html?fbclid=IwAR2S2MlcbBQDNAT1jaFWfmVboMU9rAtuVOGv2WJAtGB1lQvJswlHyirg71M